# Unable to test query but need best indexing strategy for WHERE OR.. OR.. OR clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization, indexing, sql-server-2012

An application runs a routine once a week. The last run was extremely slow and we know that more data will be processed during the next run. The slowest statement in the routine, by far, joins a temp table to a products table. Profiler shows a very high number of reads, suggesting it is not indexed well. During the last run, the Products table had 200,000 rows and the temp table had 1200.

```
 update tmp      
 set tmp.col1 = pd.col1, 
     tmp.col2 = pd.col2, 
     tmp.col3 = pd.col3 
 from #temptable tmp
, Products pd with (nolock)      
 where tmp.col2 = pd.col2 
    or tmp.col2 = pd.col3 
    or tmp.col2 = pd.col4       
    or tmp.col2 = pd.col5
```

I only have one chance to apply an indexing strategy. The temp table is generated from data that only exists for a short period of time and no copy exists, so cannot be recreated before the next run. The plan cache does not have an execution plan.

The query should be updated to ANSI-92 but I'm dealing with it as found.

The products table has indexes on each of the columns col2, col3, col4, col5, but no covering composite or INCLUDES for the update values.

The temp table has no indexing.

I have not tried anything because there is no way to test before the next live run.

Can anyone advise whether I should apply a composite index covering the 4 Product columns, or use four indexes - one for each column and INCLUDEs for col1, col2 and col3?

Comment: you profiler should have given you the required index and average impact unless u have any scheduled restart of server. Firstly, you would need inner join

Comment: Do you have separate indexes on `products.col2`, `products.col3`, `products.col4`,  and `products.col5`? the `#temptable.col2` should be indexed as well.

Comment: Please post the query plan and table sizes as well

Comment: It has to be 1 update or you can do 4?

Comment: @Ven Profiler did not have SHOWPLANXML on.

Comment: does your query runs as proc or just as query on its own

Comment: @RadimBačaSeparate indexes are on Products cols2-4. I thought that as temptable was being updated it would scan anyway. No query plan. sizes 200,000 rows and 1200 mentioned in question above.

Comment: @EzequielLópezPetrucci It could be 4 queries, if that would help.

Comment: @Ven The statement is part of a stored procedure.

Comment: I have corrected my column names in the post.

Comment: I don't really buy that it can't be replicated on another system, even with mocked up data you should be able to replicate the problems elsewhere and test properly.

Comment: @Andrew Just thinking that. I am attempting to build a table with 1200 random values that correspond to one of the 4 Product columns. But it would be nice if there was a correct answer derived from theory, not practice, to help me understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without having stats about the execution times or plans, and considering that you want to speed up as fast as possible (even with an increase in index size), I would suggest creating 4 covering indexes (one on each column)

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NCI_Products_col2 ON Products (col2) INCLUDE (col1, col3)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NCI_Products_col3 ON Products (col3) INCLUDE (col1, col2)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NCI_Products_col4 ON Products (col4) INCLUDE (col1, col2, col3)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NCI_Products_col5 ON Products (col5) INCLUDE (col1, col2, col3)
```

And dividing your update in 4 steps:

```
-- join by col2 (skip tmp.col2 update)
update tmp set 
    tmp.col1 = pd.col1, 
    tmp.col3 = pd.col3 
from 
    #temptable tmp
    INNER JOIN Products pd with (nolock) ON tmp.col2 = pd.col2 


-- join by col3
update tmp set 
    tmp.col1 = pd.col1, 
    tmp.col2 = pd.col2, 
    tmp.col3 = pd.col3 
from 
    #temptable tmp
    INNER JOIN Products pd with (nolock) ON tmp.col2 = pd.col3

-- join by col4
update tmp set 
    tmp.col1 = pd.col1, 
    tmp.col2 = pd.col2, 
    tmp.col3 = pd.col3 
from 
    #temptable tmp
    INNER JOIN Products pd with (nolock) ON tmp.col2 = pd.col4

-- join by col5
update tmp set 
    tmp.col1 = pd.col1, 
    tmp.col2 = pd.col2, 
    tmp.col3 = pd.col3 
from 
    #temptable tmp
    INNER JOIN Products pd with (nolock) ON tmp.col2 = pd.col5
```

So by removing the `OR` joins, each update *should* use it's covering index. You might need to wrap in transaction if you need the operation to be handled as whole.

Please verify the update order, executing in different order might yield different results by the nature of your original query (if `tmp` `col2` can be found in `Product` `col3` *and* `col5` for **different records**, values to update might be different).

Comment: Thanks. I made a mocked up temptable and applied this without the indexes. It ran instantly. The execution plan showed that the original was stuck on a Nested Loop (97%). I'll put my findings in an update later.

Answer (score 2):

Your question has limitation as you can not get the `showplan`, i would rather say follow these approaches.
Note: this gives a hint of indexes and expensive queries if your server is not restarted since last time your proc has run.

If you use inner join of temp table to product table, you will enhance query execution.

Follow these approaches

1) Check for most expensive query by `query_stats`, use the following script to isolate if that stored proc is in the list of expensive queries

```
SELECT TOP 5 t.TEXT AS 'SQL Text'
    ,st.execution_count
    ,ISNULL(st.total_elapsed_time / st.execution_count, 0) AS 'AVG Excecution Time'
    ,st.total_worker_time / st.execution_count AS 'AVG Worker Time'
    ,st.total_worker_time
    ,st.max_logical_reads
    ,st.max_logical_writes
    ,st.creation_time
    ,ISNULL(st.execution_count / DATEDIFF(second, st.creation_time, getdate()), 0) AS 'Calls Per Second'
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats st
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(st.sql_handle) t
ORDER BY st.total_elapsed_time DESC
```

2)  Also check for index requirements for any recent queries run in the server, this is an excellent script from Pinal gives us need for indexes, if you can not re run the query manually or do not have showplan
https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/01/03/sql-server-2008-missing-index-script-download/

```
SELECT TOP 25
dm_mid.database_id AS DatabaseID,
dm_migs.avg_user_impact*(dm_migs.user_seeks+dm_migs.user_scans) Avg_Estimated_Impact,
dm_migs.last_user_seek AS Last_User_Seek,
OBJECT_NAME(dm_mid.OBJECT_ID,dm_mid.database_id) AS [TableName],
'CREATE INDEX [IX_' + OBJECT_NAME(dm_mid.OBJECT_ID,dm_mid.database_id) + '_'
+ REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(ISNULL(dm_mid.equality_columns,''),', ','_'),'[',''),']','') 
+ CASE
WHEN dm_mid.equality_columns IS NOT NULL
AND dm_mid.inequality_columns IS NOT NULL THEN '_'
ELSE ''
END
+ REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(ISNULL(dm_mid.inequality_columns,''),', ','_'),'[',''),']','')
+ ']'
+ ' ON ' + dm_mid.statement
+ ' (' + ISNULL (dm_mid.equality_columns,'')
+ CASE WHEN dm_mid.equality_columns IS NOT NULL AND dm_mid.inequality_columns 
IS NOT NULL THEN ',' ELSE
'' END
+ ISNULL (dm_mid.inequality_columns, '')
+ ')'
+ ISNULL (' INCLUDE (' + dm_mid.included_columns + ')', '') AS Create_Statement
FROM sys.dm_db_missing_index_groups dm_mig
INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_missing_index_group_stats dm_migs
ON dm_migs.group_handle = dm_mig.index_group_handle
INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_missing_index_details dm_mid
ON dm_mig.index_handle = dm_mid.index_handle
WHERE dm_mid.database_ID = DB_ID()
ORDER BY Avg_Estimated_Impact DESC
GO
```

Ps: This solution is just and indication of required indexes, mostly use your intuition

Comment: The statement did not appear in the query_stats and the indexes in Pinal's script were not related to problem. Otherwise, those are great techniques I'll use again.